# I am tiring/fatigue in driving

Tags: word-choice

> After a hard day's work or a sleepless night, I am **tiring/fatigue** in driving.

Which sentence sounds more correct?

Comment: *none!* After working hard for the whole day or a sleepless night, I am tired to drive.

Comment: @MaulikV *I am **too** tired to drive.*  Your clause, *\*I am tired to drive*, is ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailboat What if I'm not **'too'** tired but just tired?

Comment: @MaulikV: Then you are tired **when** / **while** driving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, "fatigue" is mostly used as noun, or as the participial adjective "fatiguing". Often used in rather technical/scientific speak, it's not the word you want in your sentence.

Now to the grammar:

The noun "driving" should be replaced by the verb "drive",

> After a hard day's work or a sleepless night, I am **too tired to drive**.

Or - but with a different meaning -

> After a hard day's work (e.g. as taxi driver) or a long trip, I am **tired of driving**.

Answer (score 1):

Fatigue can also appear as "[fatigued](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/fatigue#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_fatigue_2)".

> After a hard day's work or a sleepless night, I am **too fatigued to** drive.

[2fatigue verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatigue)
: to make (someone) tired
transitive verb
 1.  to weary with labor or exertion
 2.  to induce a condition of fatigue in
intransitive verb
:  to suffer fatigue